# How to create a directive to validate form remotely?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I am creating a remote validation directive that allows me to check with my server if the field is validated.

So far I have this:

```
angular.module('Form').directive('remoteFieldValidation', function (Query) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                fieldValue: '=ngModel'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                element.parent().addClass('has-feedback');
                element.focusout(function (value) {
                    var value = scope.fieldValue;
                    var checker = attr.remoteFieldValidation;
                    if (value && checker) {
                        element.parent().append('<span class="form-control-feedback fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="line-height: 35px"></span>');
                        Query.api2({
                            method: 'GET',
                            route: 'validateField',
                            params: {
                                value: value,
                                checker: checker
                            }
                        }).then(function (result) {
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Missing checker or value');
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

For clearance Query is my own API service basically it controls `$http requests`.

Now when I add this attribute directive to an input field I would like to make sure that once it starts validating it sets the form as invalid.

However I'm not quite sure how to reach the form from this directive.

Does anyone know how I might do this to prevent that users submit the form before my remote validation is checked?

Comment: You can read about how to implement async validator here: http://jaysoo.ca/2014/10/14/async-form-errors-and-messages-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a static way just by making your submit action wait the server to validate your field. However, a better approach would be adding an [`$asyncValidator`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) on your `ngModel`. It's a feature brought on AngularJs 1.3 release.

By using this solution you'd be able to catch the validation errors using angular form atributes:

```
<div ng-show="form.myField.$error.myRemoteValidator">The value is not valid!</div>
```

Or using [`ngMessages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) like so:

```
<div ng-messages="form.myField.$error">
    <div ng-message="myRemoteValidator">The value is not valid!</div>
</div>
```

Your directives would look like:

```
angular.module('Form')
     .directive('remoteFieldValidation', function(Query, $q) {
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
           ngModelCtrl.$asyncValidators
             .myRemoteValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
               var value = modelValue || viewValue;
               var checker = attr.remoteFieldValidation;

               return Query.api2({
                 method: 'GET',
                 route: 'validateField',
                 params: {
                   value: value,
                   checker: checker
                 }
               }).then(function(result) {
                 if (result.isValid) {
                   // it says to validator that it's valid
                   return true;
                 } else {
                   // it says to validator that it's not valid
                   // and also send the error message
                   return $q.reject('Invalid field');
                 }
               }, $q.reject); // invalidate in case of any errors on your api or request 
             };
         }
       }
     });
```

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
<form name="form">
    ...
    <input type="text" ng-model="myField" remote-field-validation>
    <div ng-messages="form.myField.$error">
        <div ng-message="myRemoteValidator">The value is not valid!</div>
    </div>
    ...
    <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: where would i put my directive? on which field?

Comment: You must add it to the field which has the `ngModel` you need to validate. I've used an alias to a field called `myField` but you got the idea and use your own just make sure that it's on ngModel because the $asyncValidator comes from ngModel controller.

Comment: thank you but where do i put the ngMessage? is that on the same directive or on a seperate div block?

Comment: `ng-messages` will trigger with form validation, it can be put wherever you want to display your validation messages just make sure to be on the same controller that the main form.

Comment: thank you can you post your html just so i know exactly how it works

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Suggestion: return promise from .api2() instead of creating a new promise

Comment: I've used a separated promise just to clarify how this works but yes is a good idea returning the API promise. I'll update later as soon as the asker get this working. Thanks @Icycool

Comment: @MarcRasmussen did you get this done? did it work or you have found a problem?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro thank you so much for your help <3